# Vue - Percent of how many field has filled on form

Tags: javascript, forms, percentage, fill

I want to know how many percent of the data function is filled;

```
console.log(this.$data);
```

This is giving that

[image]

I am planing to count all of these fields. Even if they are an object I will count each key of object.

Then I am planing to also count which one of them is filled. Then i will get percent. If you thing there is better I need your help.

Comment: what is your definition of ' full ' ? for each key ? non null values ? is an empty array value considered full or empty ?

Comment: array can be skiped just if length of array bigger than 0 it will be full for me, for object yes i want to check each key from each object and also string

Comment: Well firstly properly define what ' empty ' or ' full ' means. But yes, you can filter the array of object values . get the length. and use that to get the percentage.

Comment: these all datas is already defined when page loaded,but they are empty. user will fill them step by step. Just because most of them is nullable and i want to make user fill them as much as possible i want to show them how many percent of all filled has filled by any value. Instead of full i meant filled sorry.